# SASS @extend a generated class

Tags: css, sass

I'm using Bootstrap v5 and there's a utilities file that basically generates a number of classes.
In another file, I'm looking to `@extend` that generated class.

See here for the bootstrap file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.0.0-beta2-prep/scss/_utilities.scss

You'll see there's a float input that will generate .float-end, .float-start, .float-none (and breakpoints ie .float-sm-end).

I want to @extend .float-end but I get the error:
`SassError: The target selector was not found.`

My main SCSS file is setup like..

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/accordion";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// import my files
@import 'myfile';
```

I thought @extend ran AFTER everything else so I couldn't see a reason why that wouldn't work. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Appreciate your time in advance.

Comment: Try `@import 'bootstrap-utilities';`.

Comment: @Simplicius I'm actually importing each item. I just used the above example to show bootstrap comes first, then my files.

Comment: Edited question with actual contents of file.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also provide the relevant `@extend`-style-rule from your stylesheet.

Comment: ```.button {
 @extend .float-end, .btn-primary;
}```